# Hierarchical input select

Tags: r, shiny

Could you please help me solving an issue related to Hierarchical input select.

I build a simply app for hierarchical input selecting, where the choices of each selectInput are updating based on the previous user selection.  The app works, but I have found some strange behavior, which I want to avoid if possible.

My first input is the sliderInput, where the user can select which rows of the **mtcars** table should be used for the further sub-selection.

Then the selected **cars** are shown in the first selectInput and after the user choose which **cars** he want to see, the second selectInput **mpg** is filtered respectively.

Then after pressing an Action button, the sub-selection is displayed as table output.

When the user start the procedure from the beginning by changing the sliderInput, only the **cars** choices are updated. If we press on **mpg** selectInput we can still see the old selection.

Off course when we select again some **cars** the **mpg** are getting updated.

Do you know some way to avoid this behavior. My goal is, that **mpg** is always empty after the sliderInput is getting updated and not showing the old selections.

Thank you.

John

[image]

```
#  Hierarchical inputSelect Example with mtcars
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        fluidRow(
            column(width=2,
                   sliderInput(inputId = "RowsINP",label = "Rows",min=1, max = dim(mtcars)[1], value=16,step=1),
                   selectInput("carsINP", "cars", choices = NULL,multiple=TRUE),
                   selectInput("mpgINP", "mpg", choices = NULL,multiple=TRUE),
                   actionButton("actionINP", "action")
            ),
            column(width=10,
                   tableOutput('table')
            )
        )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
    mtcars_tab <-  reactive({
        req(input$RowsINP)
        data.frame(cars=rownames(mtcars[1:input$RowsINP,]),mtcars[1:input$RowsINP,])
    })
    observeEvent(mtcars_tab(), {
        updateSelectInput(session,"carsINP", choices = unique(mtcars_tab()$cars))
    })
    cars <- reactive({
        req(input$carsINP)
        filter(mtcars_tab(), cars %in% input$carsINP)
    })
    observeEvent(cars(), {
        # Also tried this option and many others
            #  if (!isTruthy(input$carsINP[1])){choices <- NULL}
            #  else{ choices <- unique(arrange(cars(),mpg)$mpg)}
        choices <- unique(arrange(cars(),mpg)$mpg)
        updateSelectInput(session, "mpgINP", choices = choices)
    })
    mpg <-eventReactive(input$actionINP,{
        filter(cars(), mpg %in% input$mpgINP)
    })
    output$table <- renderTable(mpg())
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, [uiOutput/renderUI](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.4.0/renderUI.html) is perfect for these situations. We can avoid using a bunch of `observeEvent` and `updateSelectInput` calls, and the dropdown choices are updated (effectively) instantaneously, so you won't see the issue you've shown in your example. I think it's also a little bit easier to follow.

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

ui <- {
    fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
            sliderInput(inputId = "rows",label = "Rows",
                min=1, max = dim(mtcars)[1],
                value=16, step=1),
            uiOutput('car_selector'),
            uiOutput('mpg_selector'),
            actionButton('action', 'Action'),
            dataTableOutput('table_data')
        )
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    # render the car selection input
    output$car_selector <- renderUI({
        selectInput('car_input', 'Cars',
            choices = rownames(mtcars)[1:input$rows],
            multiple = TRUE)
    })
    
    # render the mpg selection input
    output$mpg_selector <- renderUI({
        selectInput('mpg_input', 'mpg',
            choices = mtcars[rownames(mtcars) %in% input$car_input, 'mpg'],
            multiple = TRUE)
    })
    
    # update the table data when the action button is clicked
    table_data <- eventReactive(input$action, {
        mtcars[rownames(mtcars) %in% input$car_input & mtcars$mpg %in% input$mpg_input, ]
    })
    
    # render the table data
    output$table_data <- renderDataTable(table_data())
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Dear heds1, Thank you very much for the proposal. Actually my original script is based on your idea and it works. The issue is, that in my original code I am using much larger table and by render new UI selectInput I must filter each time by adding the new condition. If you repeat it 30th times with a large table renderUI must perform 30 filtering procedures from the scratch. In my example we are just adding the new criteria, which make the performance much better. Thank you. John